# Using facing as an optional rule from DMG (p.252)

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, facing

Are you using optional rules for facing? 
If so can you share some insight?

I like that optional rule but me and my players foresee some potential problems.
For instance...
Two characters are dueling, what's to stop one another from always going behind each others back. Sure the character who is getting flanked can use reaction to turn, however the flanking character can move, attack, move again and attack effectively getting Advantage on the second attack. 
Other option for flanked character is it's use reaction for AO (since the flanker has effectively moved out of reach when he moves to back) but flanked character opens himself for (potentially) multiple attacks with Advantage.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site. As RPG.se isn't a discussion site, questions that wish to survey users for their opinions and ideas are not a good fit as answers would [all be equally valid](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). This would need to be rephrased to be about a specific problem you are having to be answerable in our Q&A site format. If you do just want to hear people's thoughts and ideas though, you may want a [discussion forum instead](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449).

Comment: It seems like the poster is asking how this rule can be used in conjunction with existing rules without breaking a lot of those other rules. WotC placed the optional rule in there with apparently insufficient support.If the answer can be given within that context, using the RAW as a guideline, I don't see it as opinion-based. Maybe it could be reworded to ask how existing rules interact with this optional rule? In any case, it sounds like a valid concern.

Comment: @keithcurtis Possibly, but it also has the issue that it's asking about a *hypothetical* problem. RPG.se handles hypotheticals poorly. If they want to ask a more Q&A-suited question, actually trying the rule (perhaps in a testing game) and then asking about the *real* problems that arise would work better.

Comment: I agree that the current wording needs more focus. I think I mainly commented because I am terribly curious about the solutions. I'd like to see this question worded in a way to allow studied responses.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Tnx, I'll try this question on discussion forum.

Comment: I can change wording so that the question won't be about hypothetical problem, but that probably won't change the fact that I'm asking about opinions rather than hard facts because the rules about facing aren't that detailed. I've already Googled the problem and so far not many people were bothered about facing  rules or rather they weren't *bothering* with facing.  So, should I delete this question or...?

Comment: @kukify you can either leave it as is or delete it. Leaving it as is it'll eventually evolve from [on hold] to [closed], and it'll be helpful as a signpost to future readers of what sorts of questions might need more work before fitting the Stack. If you delete it, OTOH, you can always edit it and undelete after you've had a go at these rules ans can ratchet down the question a bit. In either case, welcome to the site, and happy gaming!